# How to get information from a website

Tags: web

Hi i was wondering how can a website get data from other websites like products, change some data and republish it ? I have seen some solution using web crawlers and was wondering if there was a more efficient solution .I have a basic understanding of coding so any help would be useful thanks .

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is called curl, look for a corresponding documentation with your method of development, if it's php

[cURL PHP](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php)